# Cómo puedo sumar horas en varios SPAN dependiendo del resultado obtenido según el médico seleccionado

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

No me doy cuenta o no tengo aún el conocimiento para entenderlo y quisiera si alguien lo tiene me podría dar una mano con mi código.
Selecciono un médico y el resultado lo traslado a unos div desde la base de datos, aquí dejo el html dónde pongo los resultados obtenidos según selección del médico. Donde dice el médico JULIO ANDRES quisiera que fuese la selección de un `SELECT` (quiero obtener el nombre que seleccione y ponerlo donde dice JULIO ANDRES), después en el botón hay una función `ONCLICK` que sumaría los horarios obtenidos desde la base de datos.

```
<html>
 <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="card-header"><i class="fas fa-table mr-1"></i>Listado de 
    Turnos</div>
   <?php 
    $objCon = new Conexion();
    $conexion = $objCon->conectar();
    $sql = "SELECT nombre, tmdesde, tmhasta, ttdesde, tthasta, cada 
    FROM lunes WHERE nombre = **'JULIO ANDRES'**";
    $resultadolunes = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); 
    while($lunes = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadolunes)) {
   ?> 
   <button type="button" onclick="**Obtenerhorariosdesdemedicos**()"> ver</button>
   <div> <h2 id="tmdesde"> <?php echo $lunes['tmdesde']?> </h2></div>
   <div> <h2 id="tmhasta"> <?php echo $lunes['tmhasta']?> </h2></div>
   <div> <h2 id="ttdesde"> <?php echo $lunes['ttdesde']?> </h2></div>
   <div> <h2 id="tthasta"> <?php echo $lunes['tthasta']?> </h2></div>
   <div> <h2 id="cada"> <?php echo $lunes['cada']?> </h2></div>
 <?php 
       }
   ?>


        <div class="input-group mb-2">
         <span class="input-group-text">8:00 a.m</span>
         <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(1)" id="texto-1" 
         type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
         <div class="input-group-append">
         <button  class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(1)" 
         disabled type="button" id="boton-1">Editar</button>
        </div>
     </div>
          
     <div class="input-group mb-2">
       <span class="input-group-text">8:15 a.m</span>
       <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(2)" type="text" 
        class="form-control" id="texto-2" placeholder="">
       <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(2)" disabled 
       type="button" id="boton-2">Editar</button>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <span class="input-group-text">8:30 a.m</span>
      <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(3)" type="text" 
       class="form-control" id="texto-3" placeholder="">
      <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(3)" disabled 
      type="button" id="boton-3">Editar</button>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <span class="input-group-text">8:45 a.m</span>
      <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(4)" type="text" 
        class="form-control" id="texto-4" placeholder="">
       <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(4)" disabled 
       type="button" id="boton-4">Editar</button>
       </div>
     </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Este es el código Javascript que al presionar el botón quiero que me sume las horas en los SPAN, actualmente lo pone en console

```
function Obtenerhorariosdesdemedicos(){
  var lunestmdesde = document.getElementById("tmdesde").textContent
  var lunestmhasta = document.getElementById("tmhasta").textContent
  var lunesttdesde = document.getElementById("ttdesde").textContent
  var lunestthasta = document.getElementById("tthasta").textContent
  var lunescada = document.getElementById("cada").textContent
   const Horario = {
      dia: {
    inicio: lunestmdesde,
    fin: lunestmhasta
      },
      tarde: {
    inicio: lunesttdesde,
    fin: lunestthasta
         },
      cada: lunescada,

      };

    var now = new Date();
     var inicial = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 
     now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), 
     Horario.dia.inicio, 0, 0, 0);
     var final  = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 
     now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), 
      Horario.dia.fin, 0, 0, 0);

     var inicialt = new 
      Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 
       now.getDay(), Horario.tarde.inicio, 0, 
       0, 0);
     var finalt  = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 
      now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), 
      Horario.tarde.fin, 0, 0, 0);

       for (var f = inicial; f <= final; 
       f.setMinutes(f.getMinutes() + 
       Horario.cada))
      {
      let hora = ("0" + 
    String(f.getHours())).slice(-2); //slice 
     para dar formato de 2 digitos
      let minutos = ("0" +  
     String(f.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
     console.log(hora + ":" + minutos );
       }
       for (var f = inicialt; f <= finalt; 
        f.setMinutes(f.getMinutes() + 
        Horario.cada))
         {
       let horat = ("0" + 
       String(f.getHours())).slice(-2); 
       //slice para dar formato de 2 digitos
       let minutost = ("0" + 
       String(f.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
       console.log(horat + ":" + minutost );
       }


      }
```

Comment: de casualidad has pasado por algun curso de html o javascript?

Comment: me puedes dar una explicacion de que crees que hace `document.getElementById`

Comment: el document.getelementbyId  toma el contenido que se muestra al seleccionar el medico, por ejemplo si selecciono un medico y los horarios de atencion es de 8:00 a 12:00 y 16:00 a 19:00 cada 30 minutos de atencion, entonces estos resultados los muestro en unos SPAN pero no anda la funcion javascript que tengo, me explico?

Comment: creo que no sabes que hace getElementById: este metodo de javascript buscan en el DOM html el primer elemento que encuentre con el ID indicado como parametro. no tiene nada que ver con lo que has dicho... entonces, si tus ID se repiten jamas va a funcionar tu script; creo que deberias de validar/estudiar la documentacion de html y javascript.  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: por eso consulto si alguien me podría ayudar con éste codigo y ovbiamente me falta un montón para aprender, pero se me presentó éste problema e hice la consulta si alguien lo sabe resolver.

Comment: ok normalmente no hacemos codigos de trabajos o tareas... en llo que ayudamos es cuando estas implementando tu codigo y te trabas en un error que no sabes resolver... ya te di la respuesta a tu error como veras el primer error que pude detectar es la forma en que pretendes que funciona javascript y getElementById ... eso debes corregirlo... al cambiar eso ... a lo mejor surgiran otros errores que podras venir a preguntar haca ... cada pregunta es para un error especifico que no puedas resolver...

Comment: el problema es que no es correcto que vengaz con el error #5 cuando no has resuelto el 1,2,3,4 ....

Comment: es verdad...!!!

Comment: gracias 
ArcanisGK507 !!! veré cómo puedo resolverlo.